# Google Analytics Event Tracking Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I'm trying to troubleshoot tracking events on a website for someone, and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Let me preface this by saying that I realize there are dozens of questions similar to this on stackoverflow, and they have been helpful in helping me rule out a lot of issues, but still an issue persists.

**In Analytics it is showing "x of your visits sent events", but then under "total events" it says zero. It also--as one would expect--has no data available for categories and actions.**

What I've tried:

- Checking to ensure that the parameters I pass are correct. I pass a
  category, action, and label all as strings, and a value as an
  integer.
- Timing issues. I realize that most times when this happens for
  people, it has been an issue where the page was redirecting before
  the event could completely fire. On my test page, however, I have
  an event firing as soon as the document is ready, and it still
  only records the same way as the buttons.
- Simply waiting for the data to gather. I wish this were the solution,
  but if data isn't gathering after 5 days, how long should I have to
  wait?

Here is a link to the test page: http://www.easybreezypreschool.com/order-now_test.htm

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your test page... using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) I could see both the _trackPageview and the _trackEvent requests being sent.

Is there a chance that there's some kind of filter set up on the Google Analytics account that's excluding your events?

Comment: I know--it's ridiculous! I'm thinking I'll just copy that script to one of my personal accounts, update the tracking code to my own, and see if the events still don't fire. Maybe something in the account is simply screwed up and I need to create a new one. 

Thanks for looking at this, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Please following following link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide 
which applies to older versions of Google Analytics: Tracking Basics (Asynchronous Syntax)

Example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('.recorddownload').on('click', function() {
      var txt = $(this).attr('title');
      $("span").text(txt);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<a class="recorddownload" href="#" title="swishing party">Click me too!</a>
<br/>
<a class="recorddownload" href="#" title="eating party dis">Click me too!</a>
<br/>
<a class="recorddownload" href="#">Click me too!</a>
<br/>
<span></span>


</body>
</html>
```

In Google analytics you could see different classifications